# How to append values to an array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm doing this:

```
for(int i=0;i>count;i++)
{
    NSArray *temp=[[NSArray alloc]initWIthObjects]i,nil];
    NSLog(@"%i",temp);
}
```

It returns to me 0,1,2,3....counting one by one, but I want an array with appending these values {0,1,2,3,4,5...}.
This is not a big deal, but I'm unable to find it. I am new to iPhone.

Comment: Don't use br tags. Use the "101010" button to format code.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   [myArray addObject:@(i)];
}

NSLog(@"myArray:\n%@", myArray);
```

Comment: Make sure to release the `NSMutableArray` afterwards!

Comment: It should probably be `i < count` in the `for` loop. But you just copied it from @user440485's original.

Answer (score 15):

This code is not doing what you want it to do for several reasons:

1. `NSArray` is not a "mutable" class, meaning it's not designed to be modified after it's created. The mutable version is `NSMutableArray`, which will allow you to append values.
2. You can't add primitives like `int` to an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` class; they only hold objects. The `NSNumber` class is designed for this situation.
3. You are leaking memory each time you are allocating an array. Always pair each call to `alloc` with a matching call to `release` or `autorelease`.

The code you want is something like this:

```
NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    NSNumber* number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i]; // <-- autoreleased, so you don't need to release it yourself
    [array addObject:number];
    NSLog(@"%i", i);
}
...
[array release]; // Don't forget to release the object after you're done with it
```

My advice to you is to read the [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html) to understand some of the basics.

Comment: Under ARC the compiler automatically inserts the necessary retain and release calls. So just do `array = nil`;

Answer (score 1):

A shorter way you could do is:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

   [myArray addObject:@(i)];
}

NSLog(@"myArray:\n%@", myArray);
```