# Add an object to a NSMutableArray using arrayWithObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsarray, nsmutablearray

This is my code:

```
NSMutableArray* notifications = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:myObject.dictionary, nil];
```

After creating the NSMutableArray I do this:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:notifications options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];
```

How can I add other objects to the NSMutableArray notification?

I know I can do something like:

```
NSMutableArray* notifications = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:object1.dictionary, object2.dictionary, object3.dictionary, nil];
```

but I want to add them after the creation of the NSMutableArray.

myObject contains this:

```
-(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.name,@"name",self.category,@"category",self.note, @"note",self.dueDate, @"dueDate",self.creationDate, @"creationDate", nil];}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append values to an array in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698152/how-to-append-values-to-an-array-in-objective-c)

Comment: No, because in this case I need to add an object using `arrayWithObject:object.dictionary`..
I update my question

Comment: I need to add an Object to `notification`, but as you can see, when I create the NSMutableArray `notification` I use `arrayWithObjects:myObject.dictionary`. How can I add another one in the same way?

Comment: Will this work: `[notifications addObjectsFromArray: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject: object.dictionary]]` ?

Comment: Fantastic. If u write as a post I give u the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one object as an array to an existing array as follows:

```
[notifications addObjectsFromArray: [NSArray arrayWithObject: object.dictionary]];
```

Alternatively, instead of `arrayWithObject`, you can also use the literal notation:

```
[notifications addObjectsFromArray: @[object.dictionary]];
```

You can add even more than one object at a time:

```
[notifications addObjectsFromArray: @[object1.dictionary, object2.dictionary]];
```

Comment: Hi - I'd simply use ```[NSArray arrayWithObject:...``` here, mutable is not required.